# What kind of support/options are there for switchable graphics on linux?

Tags: linux, graphics

I've been trying to breath new life into my brothers Lenovo t400, but it has both integrated and discrete graphics (AMD and Intel respectively). When I install any form of Linux, both cards run, making the the whole thing burning hot. I've searched for answers, but most require some command line voodoo after every start; my brother isn't the most technically minded, so I am trying to make it as easy as possible for him. Also, most of what I've found hasn't been update for a few years, so I don't know if its still applicable.

Has there been any new support for switchable graphics lately that I can take advantage of?

Comment: take a look into Fedora 20 Beta as this is one of the new features, although I don't know details.

Comment: I cant seem to find anything related to hybrid graphics. Is there a link you can provide?

Comment: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQ0ODM, check here. article with some info, but you need kernel 3.12 and not sure if it works with Amd cards, since they only mention noveua driver

Answer (score 0):

The proprietary AMD catalyst graphics driver has supported switchable graphics for a while now, however they usually have bad support for older graphics cards. You should find out whatever version of the proprietary driver is available in your distribtion's repositories, and then check its release notes to see if your card is supported. If I remember correctly switchable graphics had been added to the driver since the late 11.x series.

Although switchable graphics works, its not seamless, you will have to restart your X server every time you switch the card you are using. It is better just to keep the low power comsumption card on all the time if you don't want to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your responds, however I was hoping for something else. Being able to switch between cards seamlessly and easily is an important feature for my brother.